# Connect python code to PCF MYSQL service instance

Tags: python, mysql, pcf

Is it possible to connect my python code to mysql service instance in PCF?
if yes, how to populate connection details in the code below? any suggestions.
I want to run the python code in my local machine.

Code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

try:
     connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='XXXXXXX',
                                          database='XXXXXXXXX',
                                          user='XXXXX',
                                          password='XXXXXXXXX')

    
    mySql_Create_Table_Query = """CREATE TABLE example( 
                             Id int(11) NOT NULL,
                             Name varchar(250) NOT NULL) """

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(mySql_Create_Table_Query)
    print("btp Table created successfully ")

except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Failed to create table in MySQL: {}".format(error))
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about mysql creds then you can simply create a service-key and that would display all the details...